# Hold onto iOS 6 layout in iOS 7 for Minor Update?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got an app that I made a few months ago, and since the latest version was released back in iOS 6, it has the iOS 6 look even when you download it on an iOS 7 device.  Now I want to add a quick, one-line bug fix that a user pointed out.

Thing is, when I open it in Xcode 5, now it's all like "Hey, iOS 7 is awesome!  You're doing that now!"

I'm all for reformatting for iOS 7, but it'll take considerable time to deal with all the new layouts and art assets and such.  Is it possible to tell my app to keep using the iOS 6 look for now, so I can do this quick update?  I tried changing the "View As" option on the Storyboard to 6.1, but that only seems to affect the way the storyboard looks in Xcode.  Build and run, and we're still looking at iOS 7 stuff.  My target deployment is 6.1, but I'm running on an iOS 7 device.

Are we locked into iOS 7 for everything we touch now?  I mean, it's beautiful, but it seems crazy to force everything into it as soon as we open the file...  Didn't we learn anything from King Midas?

Is there a way to keep using iOS 6 until my iOS 7 design update is ready?  Or can we basically not update our apps until we come into line with the new look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you also mentioned, changing the View as option only affects how xcode handles your storyboard or xib files.

Some people says installing older IOS into XCode 5 but it creates other troubles.

In order to make quick and minor updates, go to apple developer portal and download XCode 4.6.3. After the download, don't save it to your applications folder and put it somewhere else (like your desktop). Open your project with it and do your updates.

This was the easiest method I could find.

I hope it helps...

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Kind of a pain, but if downloading an old program is the only thing I have to do, that's an easier solution than I was expecting!  :)

Comment: Also beware that this solution will not work forever.  In a few months or so Apple will probably stop accepting apps built with Xcode 4.x